# Database to store & process client logs efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, logging, relational-database

So the context is that I have a client application that generates logs and I want to occasionally upload this data to a backend. The backend will function as an analytics server, storing, processing and displaying this data - so as you can imagine there will be some querying involved.

In terms of data collection peak load, I expect to have about 5k clients, each generating about 50 - 100 lines per day, and I'd like the solution I'm tackling to be able to process that kind of data. If you do the math, thats upwards of 1 million log lines / month.

In terms of data analytics load, it will be fairly low - I expect a couple of us (admins) to run queries to harvest some info once a week or so from all the logs.

My application is currently running RoR + Postgres, though I'm open to using a different dB if it maps better to my needs. Current contenders in my head are MongoDB & Cassandra, but I don't really want to leave Postgres if it can scale to get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my experiences, you will need an search engine to do troubleshooting and analysis when you have a lot of logs, instead of using database. (Search engine will more faster than database.)

For now, I am using logstash+Elasticsearch+Kibana total solution to build up my Log system.

- [Logstash](http://logstash.net/) is a tool can parse the logs and make it more human
  readable.
- [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/) is a search engine to do indexing and
  searching on your logs.
- [Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) is a webUI that you can use it
  to communicate with your Elasticsearch.

This is an Kibana Demo website. You can visit it. http://demo.kibana.org/  .
It provides the search interface and analysis tools such as Pie chart, Table, etc.

In my project, My application generates over 1.5 million logs per day. This Log system can handle all this logs.

Enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a purpose built tool like `logstash` for this:

http://logstash.net/

Another alternative would be Apache Flume:

http://flume.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a database solution that will grow with requests, then I would recommend looking beyond Postgres.

Cassandra is really well-suited for time-series data, though key-value stores are not suited for ad-hoc analytics. One idea could be to store your logs in Cassandra, and then roll them up into a different system later.

For straightforward storing-and-displaying of data, take a look at [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/), a realtime graphing project.

You can create your own custom graphs with Graphite, and save them as dashboards.

[image]